# how can i keep a folder in my mobile storage and a folder in my dropbox space in Sync?

Tags: android, synchronization, dropbox-api

i have developed a android app for farmers. it is a informative app for indian farmer.The users will be sending me the images and video files to me through my app. here i used (integrated) dropbox to receive those files directly to my dropbox space. whatever the image or video taken by the user, it will be stored on a folder in my mobile storage. Here what i want is, i want the folder in my mobile storage to be in sync with the folder in my dropbox. 
How can i do this?

there is a app in market called [Foldersync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) which exactly fulfil my requirement. how they are doing it? How can i keep a folder in my mobile storage and a folder in my dropbox to be in Sync?

Note :

i have gone through drop-box api and created a simple app to send files directly to my dropbox space and i know how to download a entire folder from dropbox.

But here my question is unique from that... pls don't answer the above points which i already know..

Please help!
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Dropbox API to keep a local client in sync with Dropbox. There are two main pieces to this:

1) Metadata:

Assuming you're using the Core API, the best way to get information about all of the file and folders in an account (or optionally under a specific path) is to use /delta:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta

With this, you can get information about everything your app can see, and then easily stay up to date with changes. There are some useful blog posts on using /delta here:

https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2013/12/efficiently-enumerating-dropbox-with-delta/
https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2013/12/filtering-dropbox-delta-results-by-path/

2) File content:

Using the metadata retrieved from #1, you can download any files you need access to locally using /files (GET):

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET

You can upload locally changed files using /files_put:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put

Or, for larger files, use chunked uploading:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#chunked-upload
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#commit-chunked-upload

The main work here will involve programming the logic in your app to correctly receive changes from the server as well as upload local changes, in order to keep everything in sync.

Also, be aware that on mobile devices, bandwidth can be limited and/or expensive, so be careful to not accidentally automatically download a lot of data the user doesn't want or need.

Comment: Hi Greg can i have any working example code for this syncing between two folders? it would be very much helpful for me... Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe Dropbox has any example code for this use case specifically.

Comment: Thats ok @Greg. Thanks for your response :)